# Show/Share own Google Maps Timeline to others

Tags: google-maps

My smartphone logs all my visited places via GPS and Google Maps Timeline. This way I can review where I've been.

https://www.google.com/maps/timeline

Is there any way to grant access (or share) my timeline to other persons so they always know where I'm currently at?

I noticed a small lock icon on my timeline website saying 'Visible only to you' but I cannot change this setting. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google+ lets you share your location to specific people or Circles.

[Google Support: Share your location](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6319687?p=plus_location)

You can control whether this happens through your [Google+ Settings](https://plus.google.com/settings) under "Location Sharing".

Unfortunately, you'll need your Android device to add and remove people from being able to see your location. (You can remove people/Circles from sharing on the web in your settings, just not add.)

From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6319687?p=plus_location):

> To set up Location Sharing, complete these steps on your Android device.
>
> 1. Turn on [Location History](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3118687) if you haven't already. This setting provides Location Sharing with recent location information so you can share it with others.
> 2. Download the [Google+ app](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) from the Play Store if you haven't already.
> 3. Open the Google+ app [image: Google+ icon].
> 4. On the top left, touch the menu icon [image: Menu]. A panel will appear on the left.
> 5. Choose **Settings**.
> 6. Select the account you'd like to update.
> 7. Touch **Location sharing**. Under "Location Sharing," turn on the switch. The label "On" will appear.
> 8. Share your real-time location with people and circles. (If you don't add anyone, your location won't be shared.)
>
>    - To share your exact location: Under "Pinpoint Location," touch **Choose people to share with**. On the list that pops up, select the people and circles you'd like to share with. Touch **Done** at the bottom.
>    - To share your city-level location: Under "City Location," touch **Choose people to share with**. On the list that pops up, select the people and circles you'd like to share with. Touch **Done** at the bottom.

It seems that to see your location, someone would need to be using Google+ on their smartphone or the "classic" G+. I don't see location in the new G+ (currently in preview). On the web, that's visible at your profile. With the Android app, "Locations" is one of the options in the main menu where you can see all of the locations shared with you.

A further note: Google *removed* location sharing from the iOS version of their apps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it maybe. Since they removed Google+ from the Youtube comments section, I deleted my profile. Guess I have to revive it ...